# Is there a way to design a classmate icon in CSS

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a design like the icon of this page:

[image]

This is as far as I could get:

```css
   .classmate-icon{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
  }

  .left-dot {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
    border-radius: 50%;
    float:left; 
    bottom: 5px;   
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .right-dot {
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
    border-radius: 50%;
    float:right;
    top:2px;
    display: inline-block;
  }


  .classmate-logo{
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Bradley Hand ITC";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:5px;
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .4);
    text-align: center; 
    bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 5px;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="classmate-icon">
    <div class="classmate-logo">classmate</div>
    <span class="left-dot"></span>date:<br>page:
    <span class="right-dot"></span>
</div>
```

I'm not able to create the two apostrophe signs and make the square wavy, also I can't get the date and page thing below each other without affecting other things.

Comment: Do you have the original diagram? Maybe png, jpeg ..etc

Comment: 1. You're essentially trying to insert images. But pure CSS is not a paint tool; it can't make any shape on its own. 2. You really should format text by wrapping it and using CSS. But minimal change way: swap out <br> for <br/><br/>.

Comment: inserting the original image is a good idea, thanks!

Comment: @parth108 Why in CSS and not in SVG that would be better suited for something like this? (is there any type of restriction?)